# Time zone error when using RPostgres to connect to Azure database

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I've been having trouble connecting to an Azure Postgres database via RPostgres using RStudio.

When I try to connect using 
`dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname = db, host=host_db, port=db_port, user=db_user, password=db_password)`
I get the message:

```
Warning message:
Invalid time zone 'UTC', falling back to local time.
Set the `timezone` argument to a valid time zone.
CCTZ: Unrecognized timezone of the input vector: ""
```

This message is the same when I define the time zone in the connection string except it has my defined time zone mentioned.

```
Invalid time zone 'Australia/Melbourne', falling back to local time.
```

Using dbFetch then gives the error:

```
Error: CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: ""
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on here? I previously used the same package to connect to an AWS database with no problem.

I'm using RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554, R version 4.2.1, RPostgres 1.4.4 and PostgreSQL 11 via Azure. I'm also connecting to Azure from behind a corporate VPN. I've made successful connections via other apps (e.g. pgAdmin, QGIS)

Regards,

Adrian

Comment: This is not a PostgreSQL message. The problem must be in R or the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely with the RPostgres package. I just tried the RPostgreSQL package which worked. I still don't know what the error with the RPostgres package is but at least there is a simple workaround.